# get all the values of a specific field of a datastore for each users using bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to get all the log in times of each users from our data store.
fields of the data store are

```
users, logInTime, LogOutTime, ...
```

I know I can use `count(logInTime)` and group it by `users` to see how many times a user logged in to our system, but how can I get all the logged in times in a list?
Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the group_concat function so something like this:

```
select 
userid, group_concat(logInTime,'|')
from table
group by userid
```